# Facebook App on custom subdomain

Tags: facebook, dns

I'm hosting website on heroku, and added two custom domains(with no SSL), and I can't get facebook API to work on it, if I put heroku URL I get error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.herokuapp.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.custom-domain.pl".  
The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Even though in FB there is http://.

When I'm trying to put custom domain URL, in developer tab I get

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. 
It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Any idea how can I get facebook app to work on custom domains?

Comment: For now I made walkaround, all content is in iframe, but that doesn't seem right, so if anyone have a clue

Comment: I think you can do nothing but add https support for your website. For your second issue, can you give a screenshot of the problem? Thanks

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid that, since SSL support for website generates more costs, and my website is mostly static with no need for https. Heroku by default gives https, and I can't avoid that. My second issue is obviously wrong since subdomain routes to to heroku app, urls just don't match. So there is no way to make facebook app in https site with http subdomain?